# High Evolutionary's face in Guardians of The Galaxy 3

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-3

In "Guardians of The Galaxy: Vol. 3" the main antagonist is *His High Evolutionary*. In the later part of the film, he appears with his face being stitched to his head like it was some sort of a mask. Why is that?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an earlier scene we see Rocket attack the High Evolutionary, scratching his face with his claws.

It would appear that he was not able to heal his face and now [wears a mask](https://youtu.be/dj5eMWQUUn0?si=LcDJd5UBaAaTIIL7&t=29) to conceal the extent of his injuries.